# Is the number before selector name in crash log meaningful to developer?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime

Sometimes, we can see some log trace with line number as 0 as the following:

```
Thread 21 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001a04cf28c objc_release + 16
1   MyApp                               0x000000010252eec0 __30-[MyAPIClient invoke:]_block_invoke.115 (MyAPIClient.m:0)
2   MyApp                               0x00000001023876fc __63-[MyTask continueWithExecutor:successBlock:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke (MyTask.m:0)
3   ...
```

That's because related code is in block.
But for the numbers `__30` and `__63` above, are the numbers before the selector name meaningful? Or are they just numbers assigned to related blocks during compilation?

Comment: You may have some luck [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/examining-the-fields-in-a-crash-report#Backtraces). I would say that _NN is a compiler generated reference (some closure in you case)